# What are the pros and cons of using microtype or LuaTeX's inbuilt microtypography features?

Tags: luatex, microtype

Both the `microtype` package and LuaLaTeX appear to offer the ability to use protrusion and expansion for microtypographic improvement.  However, as a recent convert to LuaLaTeX, I'm quite confused as to what the tradeoffs are of using LuaLaTeX vs. `microtype`.   Does one tend to produce better performance than the other or have fuller features?   Does the fact that LuaTeX's features are obviously native produce better performance? I would be grateful to better understand the pros and cons of each possibility.

Comment: like any latex package microtype adds macros providing a latex interface to the facilities provided by the underlying typesetter whether that is luatex or xetex or pdftex. So the differences should be one of input syntax not output, unless you have a specific example of a luatex feature not accessible from microtype?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks!— I am so ignorant of this subject that I certainly don't have any examples of lua features not found in microtype; if you aren't aware of any, I'm content to guess htey probably don't exist